# Node Express Mongo app goes sleep mode in shared cPanel

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, cpanel, namecheap

I deployed a Node js server with Express Js and MongoDB on NameCheap cPanel. The problem is I have to refresh 2 or 3 times to get the data from the server.Otherwise its gives 404. Then it works fine but after some minutes it acts the same. I have to refresh 2 or 3 times.
`

```
const express = require("express");
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//Middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

//MongoDB linking
const uri = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}@xyz`;
const client = new MongoClient(uri);

async function run() {
    try {
        await client.connect();
        //DB Folder and Subfolder
        const database = client.db("XYZ");
        const allUsers = database.collection("All-Users");

        app.get("/allusers", async (req, res) => {
            const get = allUsers.find({});
            const allData = await get.toArray();
            res.send(allData);
        });
    } finally {
        //await client.close();
    }
}
run().catch(console.dir);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send(" Server is running just fine");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(" server running on port :", port);
});
```

`

I dont have idea what the problem is. Did anyone faced the same issue, and solved the issue?
Thank you.

Comment: Use a real hoster or a VPS for your own... What should we do here to help you?

Answer (score 0):

Do a heartbeat mechanisim, send requests every 5 minutes to the server to keep it alive, could be resource wasting though depending on what pricing/plan you use.

If you only wanna keep the website that is running as a node server on your cpanel, you can use cron jobs as a method, chose */5 as minutes, it means running every 5 minutes, I don't think this will keep up the mongo db connection though if thats what you want

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.